# error: unrecognized command-line option '-rdynamic'

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, makefile, arm-none-eabi-gcc

When I generate my build for cross compilation for arm-none-eabi with cmake I have this error:

```
... is not able to compile a simple test program
...error: unrecognized command-line option '-rdynamic'
```

I have try to add the flag `-Wl,-export-dynamic` in toolchain file but `-rdynamic` is added by cmake

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wl,-export-dynamic  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_803b3.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_803b3
```

How can I remove it ?

Comment: The correct syntax is -Wl,-rdynamic (comma, no space)

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring that `rdynamic` part, the real problem is that CMake is trying to do a compiler check on your machine and your cross-compilation toolchain fails. This is to be expected because the arm-compiler is for the, well... arm machine and you are probably using something else as your workstation.

So make sure to disable the compiler check in your toolchain file. Most of the time it is simply enough to add `set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)`.